# How can I split a 60 GB file into 5 GB pieces on a Mac?

Tags: terminal, disk-utility, file-sharing, zip

I would imagine using a Disk Utility partition, but I didn't see the option in Disk Utility to split a larger partition into several.

How can it be done on a Mac?

I am doing this because I would like to [Mail Drop the file](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/218239/35504).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

OS X includes a command line tool called `split`. See `man split` or https://ss64.com/osx/split.html for all the details.

You can call `split` using the **Terminal.app** and the command:

```
split -b 5000m MYBIGFILE
```

---

To combine it again, have the receiver store all parts in a dedicated folder, open Terminal there and run

```
cat x?? > MYBIGFILE
```

(This assumes that you used the default output names when running `split`.)

Comment: Will this work with an encrypted .dmg file?

Comment: It will work with anything, the splitting doesn't care about the data getting split.

Comment: `cat x* > MYBIGFILE` will be better. `*` means that can be any character or symbol.

Comment: Just don't have any files with an "x" at the beginning if you plan to do this.

Answer (score -4):

I simply use the free software [Data Tape 3](https://www.fishbeam.com/en/datatape/). Why tampering with the fidgety Terminal?

Comment: "Fidgety" ? The `split` command is time-tested and extremely well documented. And easy as heck.

Comment: It would be much more helpful if you also explained when and how using the `split` command & Terminal might create problems, if any, contrary to the general view.