How to create a multi-part archive from a folder?
I have a large folder (1.8 million files, 40 GB on disk) that I want to archive for easy transfer.
I can zip the folder using ditto like so:
ditto -c -k --sequesterRsrc --keepParent 2-experiment-logs 2-experiment-logs.zip

And I cannot split the archive using zip like so:
zip 2-experiment-logs.zip --out 2-experiments-logs-split.zip -s 1024m

Because I get an error like so:
    zip warning: unexpected signature on disk 0 at 551121334

    zip warning: archive not in correct format: 2-experiment-logs.zip
    zip warning: (try -F to attempt recovery)

zip error: Zip file structure invalid (2-experiment-logs.zip)

How to fix this issue? Is there a way to create a split archive directly, without creating the monolithic archive as an intermediate step?
https://ss64.com/mac/ditto.html

I'm a bit reluctant to close this as a duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/218243/9058 because this doesn't directly answer your question. It solves the problem though.

Thanks for pointing me to that related QnA, @nohhillside. Just as the commenters there, I would also expect a nicer solution. There are multipart zip files, which automatically combine into one archive to be extracted as one set of files and directories. I am sure the must be a way that does this automatically and does not require consumers of the set of split zip files to use command line tools.

The error message above indicates problem with reading the zip file, not with splitting it. How big is it? Does extraction work?
