# iOS 13 (and web interface): Cannot share an iCloud folder

Tags: ios, icloud, sharing

I read about folder sharing feature recently added to iCloud ([Can I share iCloud Drive folder with other iCloud user?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151114/can-i-share-icloud-drive-folder-with-other-icloud-user) and [here](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2019/08/13/share-icloud-folders-tutorial/)).

Although I have iOS 13+ on my phone, I still cannot share folders. When I select folders, sharing button became grey and inactive. I checked web interface (icloud.com) and see the same behaviour.
[image]
Should I do something to activate this feature?

Answer (score 4):

iCloud folder sharing was included in some of the early iOS 13 beta releases but Apple removed that feature in Sept 2019.

As of now, iOS 13.1.3 is publicly available stable version and Apple has not added iCloud folder sharing back.

Some sites, like [this 9to5Mac site](https://9to5mac.com/2019/10/08/icloud-folder-sharing/) as well as [this Apple macOS Catalina features page](https://www.apple.com/macos/catalina/features/) are reporting that it should be available again in the "Spring of 2020".